# asp.net translation function gives junk letters for non-English characters when used in javascript file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core-localization

We were using window. resourcekeytotranslationmap function to get the localized strings from javascript file. The function gives junk characters for non-english letters. Is there any other function that can be used

Comment: You’ll have to show some code. I also can’t find any reference to such function anywhere online, is that really something in ASP.NET?

Comment: I have to show error message, if certain condition doesn't met. So at that time, I am adding error strings to the errors array like - errors.push(window.ResourcekeytoTranslationMap.Key1   . It works fine unless the localized string have some special characters(non-english)